# Using delegate/DLR Lambdas to override instance methods?

Tags: f#, dynamic-language-runtime, reflection.emit

In an effort to learn F# and .Net, I've been playing around with the to-be-released DLR.

To that end, I've been playing around with reflection, in an effort to implement a basic type system that integrates nicely with the clr.  While I'm able to instantiate a simple type that extends Object, I get an error when calling the method it defines.

Because at the end of the day DLR LambdaExpressions compile down to delegates, what I do is take generated MethodInfo off the generated delegate and call it, populating the stack with the args of the generated method.  Then return it.  It's at this point I get my error.

Here's my code:

```
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Reflection.Emit

type ConstructorInformation=
    {Types:System.Type array}

type MethodInformation=
    {ParamTypes:System.Type array;
     Name:string
     Impl:System.Delegate}


let rec addConstructors (t:TypeBuilder) (baseType:System.Type) constructorInfos =
    match constructorInfos with
        |ci::rest ->
            let cb = t.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard,ci.Types)
            let ilGen = cb.GetILGenerator()

            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
            Array.iteri (fun (index:int) _-> ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, index+1)) ci.Types
            ilGen.Emit( OpCodes.Call, baseType.GetConstructor(ci.Types) )
            addConstructors t baseType rest
        |[] -> ()

let rec addMethods (tb:TypeBuilder) baseType methodInfos =
    match methodInfos with
    |mi::rest ->
        let mb = tb.DefineMethod(mi.Name, MethodAttributes.Public, typeof<obj>, mi.ParamTypes)
        let ilGen = mb.GetILGenerator()
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        Array.iteri (fun index _ -> ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, index+1)) mi.ParamTypes
        ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, mi.Impl.Method, mi.ParamTypes)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
        addMethods tb baseType rest
    |[] -> ()

let defineType (baseType:System.Type) constructorInfos methodInfos= 
    let ab =  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly( AssemblyName("test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
    let mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("test")
    let typeBuilder = mb.DefineType("testType", TypeAttributes.Public, baseType)// | TypeAttributes.Class
    addConstructors typeBuilder baseType constructorInfos
    addMethods typeBuilder baseType methodInfos
    typeBuilder.CreateType()

type Delegate1 = delegate of obj -> obj
let echo y:#obj= (y :> obj)
let del1 : Delegate1 = new Delegate1(echo)

let mis:MethodInformation list=[{Impl=del1; Name="Echo"; ParamTypes=[|(typeof<obj>)|]}]
let cis:ConstructorInformation list=[]
let t= defineType (typeof<obj>) cis mis
let cinfo = t.GetConstructor([||])
let instance =cinfo.Invoke([||])
instance.GetType()
(t.GetMethod("Echo")).Invoke(instance, [| (1:>obj)|])
```

Here's my error, from fsi:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MethodAccessException: clo@51.Invoke(System.Object)
   at testType.Echo(Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002._main()
stopped due to error
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated-I'm a bit of a .Net newb so my mistake may be simple.

Mike Kohout

Comment: A shot in the dark - do you get the same behavior when compiling with fsc.exe?  The MethodAccessException suggests maybe something is not public, but all your code seems to generate public methods, so I'm not sure why that's happening...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Brian but it looks like it's still happening.

After compiling this with fsc/vs2008, I'm getting this(via vs2008's debugging "exception detail" pane):

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the delegate object itself isn't on the stack....it'll take some time to verify, but I think that might be my problem.

Comment: According to the Method attribute on the delegate, the method it points to is an instance method.  Which means that the delegate object itself must be on the stack.... I think  

From the MethodInfo on the delegate:
     IsSpecialName = false;
     IsStatic = false;
     IsVirtual = false;

Comment: I am as clueless now as I was at the beginning of this question.  I tried what I talked about in my last question..I tried bundling up all the args into an array(using the newarr opcode) and than calling the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it.  The generated cil was bad.  Also, I had to dynamicinvoke on the delegate, not the function it was fronting.

```
#light

open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Reflection.Emit

type ConstructorInformation=
    {Types:System.Type array}

type MethodInformation=
    {ParamTypes:System.Type array;
     Name:string;
     Impl:System.Delegate;
     mutable Field:FieldBuilder option}


let rec addConstructors (t:TypeBuilder) (baseType:System.Type) constructorInfos =
    match constructorInfos with
        |ci::rest ->
            let cb = t.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard,ci.Types)
            let ilGen = cb.GetILGenerator()

            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
            Array.iteri (fun (index:int) _-> ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, index+1)) ci.Types
            ilGen.Emit( OpCodes.Call, baseType.GetConstructor(ci.Types) )
            addConstructors t baseType rest
        |[] -> ()

let rec addMethods (tb:TypeBuilder) baseType methodInfos =
    match methodInfos with
    |mi::rest ->
        let fb = tb.DefineField(mi.Name+"_field", typeof<Delegate>, FieldAttributes.Public);
        mi.Field <- Some(fb)
        let mb = tb.DefineMethod(mi.Name, MethodAttributes.Public, typeof<obj>, mi.ParamTypes)
        let ilGen = mb.GetILGenerator()
        let arrayLocal = ilGen.DeclareLocal((typeof<obj[]>))
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fb)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, Array.length mi.ParamTypes)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof<obj>)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, arrayLocal)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, arrayLocal)
        Array.iteri (fun index _ -> ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, index)
                                    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, index+1)
                                    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref)
                                    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, arrayLocal)) mi.ParamTypes
        ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, (mi.Impl.GetType()).GetMethod("DynamicInvoke", [|(typeof<obj[]>)|]), mi.ParamTypes)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
        addMethods tb baseType rest
    |[] -> ()

let defineType (baseType:System.Type) constructorInfos methodInfos= 
    let ab =  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly( AssemblyName("test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
    let mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("test")
    let typeBuilder = mb.DefineType("testType", TypeAttributes.Public, baseType)// | TypeAttributes.Class
    addConstructors typeBuilder baseType constructorInfos
    addMethods typeBuilder baseType methodInfos
    typeBuilder.CreateType()

type Delegate1 = delegate of obj -> obj
let echo y:#obj= (y :> obj)
let del1 : Delegate1 = new Delegate1(echo)

type Delegate2 = delegate of obj * obj -> obj
let echoFirst (x:#obj) (y:#obj)=(x:>obj)
let echoFirstDelegate:Delegate2 = new Delegate2(echoFirst)
echoFirstDelegate.DynamicInvoke( [|(1:>obj);(2:>obj)|])
//let mis:MethodInformation list=[{Impl=del1; Name="Echo"; ParamTypes=[|(typeof<obj>)|];Field=None}]
//let cis:ConstructorInformation list=[]
//let t= defineType (typeof<obj>) cis mis
//let cinfo = t.GetConstructor([||])
//let instance =cinfo.Invoke([||])
//instance.GetType()
//(t.GetField("Echo_field")).SetValue(instance, del1)
//let fieldDelegate = (t.GetField("Echo_field")).GetValue(instance) :?> Delegate
//(t.GetMethod("Echo")).Invoke(instance, [| (1:>obj)|])

//del1.DynamicInvoke( [|(1:>obj)|])

let mis:MethodInformation list=[{Impl=del1; Name="Echo"; ParamTypes=[|(typeof<obj>)|];Field=None};
                                {Impl=echoFirstDelegate; Name="EchoFirst"; ParamTypes=[| (typeof<obj>);(typeof<obj>)|]; Field=None}]
let cis:ConstructorInformation list=[]
let t= defineType (typeof<obj>) cis mis
let cinfo = t.GetConstructor([||])
let instance =cinfo.Invoke([||])
instance.GetType()
(t.GetField("Echo_field")).SetValue(instance, del1)
let fieldDelegate = (t.GetField("Echo_field")).GetValue(instance) :?> Delegate
(t.GetMethod("Echo")).Invoke(instance, [| (1:>obj)|])
(t.GetField("EchoFirst_field")).SetValue(instance, echoFirstDelegate)
(t.GetMethod("EchoFirst")).Invoke(instance, [| (1:>obj);(2:>obj)|])
```